# Call current post URL in ajax

Tags: posts, jquery, ajax, javascript

I'm not very confident in AJAX unfortuantely,

Im looking to call the current post URL via ajax.

Do you have any idea how is this possible ?

So far I'm trying the following, no success . .

```
        $(document).on('click', '.send', function(e) {
        $.ajax({
            url: ajaxpagination.ajaxurl,
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: 'json',
            data: ({
              pageurl: the_slug(),
              userEmail: userEmail
            }),
            success: function( data ) {
                alert( 'Your home page hurl' + $(pageurl);
            }
        })
```

--EDIT --

From the comment of mmm I have added the script in functions.php and then callign it like below:

```
$(document).on('click', '.link', function(e) {



    var $this = $(this),
        category = $this.attr('data-event-category'),
        action = $this.attr('data-event-action'),
        label = $this.attr('data-event-label'),
        permalink =  object["permalink"]



    self.track(category, action, label);

            console.log('tracking pushed: '+category+', '+action+', '+permalink)

});
```

},

Doesn't seems to be sucessfull, I'm having an  object is not defined . .

Comment: which data do you want to receive ?

Comment: The permalink (current post url)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can retrieve the permalink of the current post in JavaScript with `wp_localize_script`.

juste try this code after the call of `wp_enqueue_script`

```
wp_localize_script(
      "script_id"
    , "object"
    , [
        "permalink" => get_post_permalink($post),
    ]
);
```

and then you can read the permalink in JavaScript in `object["permalink"]`

Comment: thanks, I have added the function,

Then in a variable i add object["permalink"]

Callng the variable then but it doesnt seem to work . . . 

I'm having gan  object is not defined

I'm updating the post if it helps . .

Comment: can you give us the URL of this page ?

Comment: its not live unfortnately . . .:(

Comment: search in the source code if you see the line `var object =`...

Comment: I don thave any bar object = ...

just the code i have updated if this help ?

what should be done ?

Thanks a lot for your time

Comment: you have to replace `script_id` by the id of your JavaScript file. look here : https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_localize_script

Comment: thanks !!

It works ! only thing ir whos the url as 'http://oui.com/?post_type=post&p=2504' instead of http://oui.com/pretty_link

(where pretty link is the name of the post)

Any idea ? It will be super !

Thanks !

Comment: got it by get_permalink() instead of (get_post_permalink) ! thanks

Comment: If I want this url to be as an attribute ? how is that possible ?